Fetching messages from SQS based on available CPU and Memory in a worker pod
I've created a .net core worker for processing documents. The worker is running inside a kubernetes container. It pulls messages from the queue and process them parallely. Currently it pulls 10 messages and process all of them in parallel. Some times the documents are so big and out of memory exceptions are being thrown. How can I fetch messages based on the available memory and CPU in the pod instead by a fixed number?
